# Implement searchview on string type listview Android

Tags: android, listview, searchview

I have a list of `items` and i want to start different activity on the basis of `item`, when i click it opens the correct activity but when i try to search list items from search view bar then it opens wrong activities.

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    sv=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
    String[] values = new String[]{item1,item2,item3,item4,}
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //linking from 1 item to other activity stars with if options//
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity1.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
            }

            if (position == 4) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), aactivity4.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);

            }
        }
    });

    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I don't know much about coding but can any one solve my problem..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are starting your activity on the basis of `position` but the `position` will be changed when you do the search because list will shrink and `positions` will change so to get data associated with the specified position in the list use [getItemAtPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition())

so changes conditions on the basis of data

```
 if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("item1")) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity1.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
            }

else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("item2")) { // use any item value here you want 
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), aactivity4.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
            }
```

Note : you can use `switch` as well instead of long `if` or `else-if` ladder

e.g You have three string

```
item 1   position 0
item 2   position 1
item 3   position 2
```

after searching item 2 you have two values in your list close to your search

```
item 2   position 0
item 3   position 1
```

so position will change so don't use it instead use the data

Code

```
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = null;
                // global string to class
                selectedValue = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

                if (selectedValue.equals("item1")) {
                                        // ^^^  use any item value here you want
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
                }

                else if (selectedValue.equals("item2")) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), aactivity4.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: So,, how can I do it ?

Comment: @WAQARALAM you just need to replace your `if-else` code with mine , and add all cases for all items , try the Code demo part

Comment: it changes nothing ..,it is still considering the position

Comment: @WAQARALAM let me know if the issue still not solved

Comment: selectedValue = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

                if (selectedValue.equals("item1")).............here selectedValue is RED

Comment: @WAQARALAM it's a simple string variable like `String selectedValue="";`  declare it like `listView` inside your `class Youactivity {  String selectedValue=""; }`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH BROTHER.....{I THINK MY PROBLEM IS RESOLVED ......}YOU ARE VERY GOOD IN YOUR WORK......I LOVE THE WAY YOU QUICKLY RESPOND TO ALL MY QUERIES....AGAIN THANKS...

Comment: @WAQARALAM thanks for the compliments , i am glad that i could help , see you around and happy coding