# search filter with clickable list view shown wrong layout when click on search result item

Tags: java, android, listview

when I click search view result item shown wrong activity layout. For example, I click item China from search result but it go to Australia. How to set clickable search filter item to take correct activity when click?

```
  final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayList<String>arrayCountry = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayCountry.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_country)));

        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayCountry);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityAustralia.class));break;
                    case 1:
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityJapan.class));break;
                    case 2:
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityChina.class));break;

                }
            }
        });
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search,menu);
        MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
        final SearchView searchView=(SearchView)item.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

In the strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name">SearchViewList</string>

<string-array name="array_country">
    <item>Australia</item>
    <item>Japan</item>
    <item>China</item>
    <item>India</item>
</string-array>
```

In menu_search.xml

```
android:title="search"

android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"

app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"

app:showAsAction="always"
```

> 

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement searchview on string type listview Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482656/implement-searchview-on-string-type-listview-android)

Comment: don't use switch against position instead use `switch(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position)){case "firstitem": ... break; }`

Comment: i would suggest you to learn some basics , you have to give a `case` label in switch and lebel should be your array items value

Comment: your case label should be of your String values